# Recently posted author list including href="author url" and class="optional"

Tags: php, wordpress, list, profile, author

I am trying to generate an author list based on recently active users on the Wordpress page including a class in the profile link. What I have this far is

```html
<div id="personae">
<ul>
<?php
$authors =  array();
$count = 0;
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  echo '';
  while ($my_query->have_posts() && $count < 3) : $my_query->the_post();
    $author_id=$my_query->post->post_author;
    $user = new WP_User( $author_id );
    if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) && in_array('contributor',$user->roles) || in_array('',$user->roles)) {
      if (!in_array($author_id,$authors)) {
        echo '<li>';
        the_author_meta('title');
        echo ' <a href="#" class="';
        the_author_meta('personaeclass');
        echo '">';
        the_author_nickname();
        echo '</a>';   
        echo '</li>';
        $count++;
        $authors[]=$author_id;
      }
    }
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  
?>

</ul>
</div>
```

which generates an almost perfect code of the 3 recent authors.

```html
<div id="personae">
<ul>
<li>Editor <a href="#" class="menu-item-1">Name</a></li>
<li>Photographer <a href="#" class="menu-item-2">Name</a></li>
<li>Journalist <a href="#" class="menu-item-3">Name</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

***I am almost there*** **I just need the links of the authors be href="author profile url" instead of #**. I have tried using         the_author_posts_link(''); which works but then there is no way to have the class="" within the link that I also need to apply.

Any suggestions how to solve this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The function `get_the_author_link()` should work. So

```
echo ' <a href="#" class="';
```

would become

```
echo ' <a href="'. get_the_author_link() . '" class="';
```

EDIT: My apologies the above will get the authors website url try:

```
get_author_posts_url($author_id)
```

Comment: apologies the above will get the authors website url try my edit.

Comment: Yes with $authorid being the id of the author e.g.1? If you hard code one of the authors id into it, what does it show?

Comment: If I put in the author id like this         echo ' <a href="'. get_author_posts_url(2) . '" class="'; it seems to have an effect, yes. But not with $AUTHORID

Comment: what value are you assigning $AUTHORID? I made that one up as it requires the authors id to get the link.

Comment: Oh, I thought         echo ' <a href="'. get_author_posts_url($AUTHORID) . '" class="'; would generate an automatic url to the right profile. it seems to generate the right url when I make it       echo ' <a href="'. get_author_posts_url(2) . '" class="'; (2 being the ID of one of the authors) the URL finally works the same url applies to all the authors on the list

Comment: You are getting $author_id in the code so toy could try that (I would have used that as an example if I noticed it earlier).

Comment: echo ' <a href="'. get_author_posts_url($author_id) . '" class="';
works perfectly. thank you howli!

Comment: No problem, feel free to make the answer as correct so others will know how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div id="personae">
<ul>
<li>Editor <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(  $author_id, get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename', $author_id ) ); ?>" class="menu-item-1"><?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id ); ?></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Reference

- [get_author_posts_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url)
- [get_the_author_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/)